# Mal guardado de numeros en una matriz en ruby

Tags: ruby, matrices

estoy imprimiendo números desde el 1 hasta el máximo día en numero en el mes actual, el problema es que me imprime por fil, números desde el 26 hasta el 31. La matriz la declare como cuadricular, pero solo estoy utilizando 5 filas, y todas las columnas, las cuales son 7.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    @array = Array.new(7 ,[]);
    first_day = Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.strftime("%A")
    last_day = Date.today.end_of_month.strftime("%e").to_i
    day = 0
    case first_day
    when "Sunday"
        day = 0
    when "Monday"
        day = 1
    when "Tuesday"
        day = 2
    when "Wednesday"
        day = 3
    when "Thursday"
        day = 4
    when "Friday"
        day = 5
    when "Saturday"
        day = 6
    end

    week = 0
    diaActual = 1
    for i in 0..5 do
        for j in 0..7 do
            @array[i][j] = diaActual
            diaActual = diaActual + 1
        end
        if diaActual >= last_day then
            break
        end
    end
```

Lo que mas importa es el for, se supone que en `@array[0][0]` debe estar el numero uno, y cuando pago `puts @array[0][0]` me sale 25, no entiendo porque me guarda los numeros mal

La impresión en una tabla es la siguiente:

```
Domingo Lunes   Martes  Miércoles   Jueves  Viernes Sábado
25       26       27      28          29      30      31
25       26       27      28          29      30      31
25       26       27      28          29      30      31
25       26       27      28          29      30      31
25       26       27      28          29      30      31
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a cómo estás creando el arreglo inicial en la siguiente línea:

```
@array = Array.new(7 ,[]);
```

Lo que esa línea hace es generar un arreglo con 7 espacios donde cada espacio tiene asignado **el mismo arreglo**. Entonces, cuando cambias el arreglo en la última iteración, se cambia para todos los espacios.

Para ver este comportamiento ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
@array.each { |a| puts a.object_id }
```

Notarás que el resultado es la impresión del mismo arreglo 7 veces, algo como esto:

```
70326928806560
70326928806560
70326928806560
70326928806560
70326928806560
70326928806560
70326928806560
```

Entonces, debes declarar un arreglo nuevo dentro de cada espacio del primer arreglo y eso lo logras pasando un bloque al *inicializador* del arreglo; por ejemplo:

```
@array = Array.new(7) { [] }
```

En este caso, tienes un arreglo con 7 espacios con un arreglo nuevo en cada uno; si haces la misma prueba con este arreglo verás que los objetos son en efecto distintos:

```
@array.each { |a| puts a.object_id }

70360695526800
70360695526780
70360695526760
70360695526740
70360695526720
70360695526700
70360695526680
```

---

Como comentario adicional te recomiendo buscar y estudiar sobre las convenciones de desarrollo en Ruby<sup>1</sup>, las cuales te darán guía sobre sus mejores prácticas; acá te muestro algunos ejemplos tomados de tu código:

1. Evita el uso de `;` a menos que sea estrictamente necesario:

   ```
    @array = Array.new(7 ,[]);  # No
    @array = Array.new(7 ,[])   # Sí
   ```
2. Utiliza siempre *snake_case* para nombrar tus variables:

   ```
   diaActual = 1  # No
   dia_actual = 1 # Sí
   ```
3. Utiliza `each` en lugar de `for`:

   ```
   for i in 0..5 do   # No
   (0..5).each do |i| # Sí
   ```
4. Aprovecha el uso de `then` en el `case` para mejorar la legibilidad:

   ```
   case first_day
   when "Sunday"    then day = 0
   when "Monday"    then day = 1
   when "Tuesday"   then day = 2
   when "Wednesday" then day = 3
   when "Thursday"  then day = 4
   when "Friday"    then day = 5
   when "Saturday"  then day = 6
   end
   ```
5. Evita repetición en tu código dentro del `case` asignando el resultado del mismo a una variable, en lugar de asignar el resultado a la variable en cada caso:

   ```
   day = 
     case first_day
     when "Sunday"    then 0
     when "Monday"    then 1
     when "Tuesday"   then 2
     when "Wednesday" then 3
     when "Thursday"  then 4
     when "Friday"    then 5
     when "Saturday"  then 6
     end
   ```

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Para más información te recomiendo revisar la [Guía de Estilos de Ruby](https://github.com/alemohamad/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README-esLA.md) de la comunidad.*</sup>